# Using Print When Expression in the last page of report

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, expression

How to print band on the last page with Print When Expression in Jasper Report?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use **Last Page Footer** or\and **Summary** band?

Answer (score 3):

If you want on last page use

```
$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("isLastPage")
```

or if you want on each page except the last one use

```
$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("isLastPage") == null
```